# old library written in .Net framework 2 use in.Net 4

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

I have no experience in using C# .Net. I have one small question. I have a library written in .Net framework 2. Will i be able to import it and use it in .Net framework 4 ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can reference a 2.0 class library from an application of a higher framework version, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the [.NET Version Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx). (There are [some caveats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656.aspx) moving to 4, but generally speaking you should be fine.)

Any problems you might see would arise from a version previous to 2. (Though I hear past 4 is a re-write, so I'm not sure how they are handling backwards compatibility. I'm sure they *have* to keep it safe, as no many people want to side-load two .net versions).