# How can a .NET 4.0 project reference an assembly that uses the v2.0.50727 runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, runtime, clr

I have a c# project I am converting from .net 3.5 to .net 4.0 in VS2010. It has references to other 3rd party dll's that have a runtime version of v2.0.50727.

How can this be? I kind of expected a warning or breakage when building or running, but I haven't. If my compiled .net 4 project is running with the .net v4.0.30319 runtime, is it running the referenced dll with the .net 2.0.50727 runtime? And therefore, I still need old versions of .net installed?

Or is the referenced dll running in the v4.0.30319 runtime?

Comment: Please see this question:

[Link here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373541/old-library-written-in-net-framework-2-use-in-net-4

Comment: Thanks for all the great responses! I also found my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216599/does-using-assembly-compiled-in-older-version-of-net-framework-affects-whole-pe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that just works automagically.  The v4 CLR has no trouble with old v2 assembly references, it translates them one-to-one to the v4 versions of those assemblies.  Or if this is a non-framework assembly then nothing magically happens, it can still read the metadata of a v2 assembly.

Rather necessary, few programmers would have opted to move up to version 4.0 if that wouldn't work.  There have been a few isolated cases where a over-due bug fix in 4.0 caused different behavior but they have been very rare.

Comment: The v4 CLR will not run the v2 assemblies. You must have the v2 CLR installed. See my answer for more details.

Comment: No.  The inprocess side-by-side feature is only enabled for custom CLR hosting scenarios.  A [ComVisible] .NET assembly getting loaded into an unmanaged process is the most common case.

Answer (score 0):

---

From the [commented question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373541/old-library-written-in-net-framework-2-use-in-net-4) to prevent link rot:

"Yes, you can reference a 2.0 class library from an application of a higher framework version, but not the other way around.

You can always check the [.NET Version Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx). (There are [some caveats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656.aspx) moving to 4, but generally speaking you should be fine.)
--Brad Christie

Any problems you might see would arise from a version previous to 2. (Though I hear past 4 is a re-write, so I'm not sure how they are handling backwards compatibility. I'm sure they have to keep it safe, as no many people want to side-load two .net versions"
--wsanville

[What does 'useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy' do in the .NET 4 config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604663/what-does-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-do-in-the-net-4-config)